# A border in a div

Tags: css, border, html

I made a span in a div. This span is only a black border, positioned above the div. 
I want this span (black border) adapts to the div width and height. Like a border in interior to this div.

My problem is that border exceed the div : http://jsfiddle.net/QHRYJ/

```
div {
    background: pink; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 200px;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit; 
    border: 4px solid;
    margin: 10px;
    height: inherit;
}
```

**-->-->-->-->**
**EDIT : what I want : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=623039div.png**

Comment: Why not add the border to the div?

Comment: Why not just add a border to the `<div>`?

Comment: your margin is what is throwing you off, just put margin to 0 and display: inline-block;

Comment: Because for my project, I want this span appears/disapears by the mouseover (jquery).

Comment: @user2657939 Just add a border to the `<div>` on hover...

Comment: And what I want is a black border inside this div, with spaces between the edges of the div and those of the span.

Comment: Add padding to the `<div>` and set `box-sizing`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments speak for themselves, however, if you still want to achieve it your way:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    background: pink; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 200px;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top:0 ;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 4px solid;
}
```

You need to give your parent div a position so its child elements orientate themselves on its parent. Then, as your span is absolutely positioned, you can just expand it by explicitly setting left, right, bottom and top to `0`.

If you want to have a spacing between span and div, add margins to the span.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.From what you've described in the comments (adding a border to the `<div>` on hover), you don't need a `<span>` element for that. You can achieve this using the `:hover` pseudo-selector. For example:

```
div:hover {
    border: 4px solid #000
}
```

Here's a [<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/QHRYJ/2/)

You might want to specify `box-sizing` on the `<div>` to prevent it from resizing:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that unless you are using `box-sizing:border-box` this will change the width of the div.